Is there a way to get the date "mask" used by Yii2 formatter automatically (according to the system language configuration)?
Here's my problem: I have a date field in a Yii2 form that I am formatting as showed in the following snippet:
<?= $form->field($model, 'date_last_purchase')->widget(DatePicker::class, [
    'language' => Yii::$app->language, // Set language based on application configuration
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'convertFormat' => true,
    ],
]) ?>

I am using the use kartik\date\DatePicker component for that.
My language configuration is set to pt-BR, and it is correctly displaying the date in pt-BR format in the form view.
However, it is not converting properly to save it in the database.The format of a pt-BR date is 'd/m/Y'. When autoconverting and saving it to the database, Yii2 is saving it as if it were 'm/d/Y'. For instance, if the date specified on the form view is 'November 5, 2024' ('05/11/2024' in pt-BR), it is storing it as '2024-05-11' (May 11, 2024).
I could disable the convertFormat option and convert it manually, but I would like to know if there is a way to make the formatter return the mask being used on the view dynamically (according to the language settings) so I can use it to make the conversion.
Or, better yet, if there is a way to tell the DatePicker widget what format it should use as input to make the conversion correctly.
Thanks in advance.

According to the DatePicker github page, there is a format option as a part of the plugin options array. Have you tried that?
e.g.
'pluginOptions' => [
    'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
    'todayHighlight' => true
]


Hi, @Richard C. Thanks for your response. I thought about using that, but I would like to retrieve the format (in your example, 'dd-M-yyyy') dynamically based on the language settings. Yii2 can format the date dynamically to show on the view page, so if I could retrieve the mask that's being used to format the value that way, I could use it in the pluginOptions.
